# What rosbag2 storage plugins are available in ROS2 galactic?

Tags: ros2, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What `rosbag2` storage plugins are available in ROS2 `galactic`? I see `sqlite3`. Is there any other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394739/what-rosbag2-storage-plugins-are-available-in-ros2-galactic?/) by [ajayvohra2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/91833/ajayvohra2005/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2022-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the default one is `sqlite3` and I couldn't find any other too.

There are some docs about development of these plugins though:

- https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/blob/master/docs/converter_plugin_development.md
- https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/blob/master/docs/storage_plugin_development.md

But they are quite old and probably now just out of date.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A new MCAP plugin was recently announced and released. https://foxglove.dev/blog/announcing-the-mcap-storage-plugin-for-ros2

---

Originally posted by [bstppldrmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/120480/bstppldrmr/) with karma: 11 on 2022-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1